# Listview Repeating Items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity

I trying make a listview with much data but when i build, item data on listview multiple repeating.

This is myJava CustomAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_Name);
        holder.Image_Block = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_Image);
        holder.Text_Recipe = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_Text);
        holder.Text_Rarity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_Rarity);

        RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        holder.Image_Block.setImageResource(row_pos.getImage_Block());
        holder.Name.setText(row_pos.getName());
        holder.Text_Recipe.setText(row_pos.getText_Recipe());
        holder.Text_Rarity.setText(row_pos.getText_Rarity());

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Anyone can fix ? Thanks

Comment: Of course, you need to set data to holder after creating or setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data isn't repeating--when you're recycling an old view, you're not initializing it to new values. Move the code that sets values (not the code that makes connections) outside of the if-else statement.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_Name);
        holder.Image_Block = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_Image);
        holder.Text_Recipe = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_Text);
        holder.Text_Rarity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_Rarity);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);
    holder.Image_Block.setImageResource(row_pos.getImage_Block());
    holder.Name.setText(row_pos.getName());
    holder.Text_Recipe.setText(row_pos.getText_Recipe());
    holder.Text_Rarity.setText(row_pos.getText_Rarity());
    return convertView;
}
```